# Web Socket Server using Apache HttpComponent NIO

Tags: websocket, nio, apache-httpcomponents

Is it possible to build a websocket server with apache httpcomponent nio server as the base?
https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore-nio/examples/org/apache/http/examples/nio/NHttpServer.java
as mentioned in above link, I can build a nio server. But is it possible to convert it to a websocet server? If so any idea on how to do that please?

Comment: is it a school assignment  or work ?  there is already a Non blocking webserver that implements the websocket API for java, not sure if can be useful for you , it is Undertow and you can check the  code here https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow

Comment: Thanks for the info Leo. But I'm looking forward to implement my own websocket server based on reactor pattern nio. So far I've implemented the basic handshake and message exchange. But the problem is whenever i send a long text message I get following error. "WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8887/' failed: A server must not mask any frames that it sends to the client. "

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys. Finally I figured it out. I had to write a custom IOEventDispatch class and execute it through IOReactor.
Within my custom IOEventDispatch class websocket connecton handling is implemented.

Answer (score -2):

Till what I have found is that, websocket is creating a tunnel from client to server(using javascript), while with nio socket you do this with total java(i.e. client can be applet but not js).
You can use websocket to transfer data fron client to server and use nio channel to write file on server.(Its feasible and look appropriate approach).